# Dice puzzle: pips must sum to 21

Tags: probability, puzzle, game-theory

A friend recently told me this little puzzle but to me it seems like there might not be a right answer. Was wondering if there is in fact a best combination in this scenario.

Dice rolling war

You and a friend decide to have a dice rolling war consisting of 36 battles. Each player will roll 1 die. A battle is won by the player with the higher number of pips, and the winner receives a point. If both players have the same number of pips, neither player receives a point. However, before starting the battles, the players get to choose the number of pips to put on the 6 sides of the die, the constraint being that the number of pips on all sides of the die must summ to 21 and be in the range [1-6]. For example,
[4][4][4][4][4][1] would be valid choice.
Finally, the person with the most points at the end of 36 rounds wins.

Part a) What pips should you choose to give you the best chance of winning?

Part b) What is the probability that you will win?

Comment: If there is an optimal combination, then there is nothing to stop your opponent doing the same, in which case the probability is definitely 50% by symmetry.

Comment: See [Nontransitive dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice). Here is a [Example](https://plus.maths.org/content/sites/plus.maths.org/files/articles/2010/grime/two_dice1.png)  of three items where it does sum to $21$. As you can see in the example, it is a nice rock-paper-scissors setup. And a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzKGnuvX6IQ) talking shortly about these kind of setups, around a four item example. I'm not sure however, if the set of all dices that sum to $21$ is transitive.

Comment: I just stumbled upon [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X06002034) that considers your problem for dices using any number of sides $n$ and summing to any number $\delta$. The solution for $6$-sided dice that sums to $21$ is unique, meaning only one optimal dice exists and it is the $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ dice, the ordinary dice. So any changes to that dice, would reduce your chances of winning. The existence of a optimal dice means both players will pick it and have equal chances of winning.

Comment: @Vepir For all 110 possible dice, I calculated the expected number of points one earns (1 for victory, 0 for draw, -1 for loss) using the die $(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3)$ and $(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)$. On average, the die $(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3)$ results in an expected gain of 0.2222, while the die $(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)$ results in an expected gain of 0.1111: https://justpaste.it/17qve. Against one another, the expected gain is 0 (probability $\frac{15}{36}$ of winning and losing, $\frac{6}{36}$ of drawing). As such, I would conclude that the die $(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3)$ is better in this case?

Comment: For every die combination, I determined the optimal die to go against it: https://justpaste.it/17qvq. The first column denotes a die combination, the second column the best die to go against it, the third, fourth and fifth column the probability of winning, drawing and losing (divide by 36) and the sixth column the expected points to win when rolling the two dice (+1 for a win, 0 for a draw and -1 for a loss).

Comment: @jvdhooft That's what the paper claims (under Example 9). Have you discovered a die that beats $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$? I did not find such a die, but I've found dies that beat $(4,4,4,3,3,3)$ such as $(1,1,4,5,5,5)$. From this I see that the original die offers at least equal chance of winning, or more. The other dies can be beaten by some radnom die more often, or win more often and this is the reason of your results against **random dies**. Playing original die is best since you are expected to win/draw in total after playing some amount of sets of rolls. Other dies are expected to lose/win/draw.

Comment: @jvdhooft Note that you are counting points among all possible opponents, at random. The true winner is the one with most points per opponent, which give most victories in total, which would be the original die. If we would play an infinite amount of games, you could not beat my $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ more often than I could any of your dies. This is not true for any other die, since other dies do have a **weak spot** = a die that will beat them **more often**.

Comment: @jvdhooft Your die **would be better indeed, but if** you were **not playing against a optimal opponent**, but one that plays all dies at random with equal chance. But **if both players play optimally, $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ is the logical choice** since it does not have a weak spot, while all other ones seem to have at least one such spot.

Comment: @Vepir You are right. As can be seen from the spreadsheet I included above, the dice $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$ is indeed the only dice which, in terms of expected wins, can never be beaten. From this perspective, it is the best choice. +1!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This was already solved

Nice question with an unexpected result.

Turns out the original die, $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ is a unique solution for the optimal die when having six sided dice that sum to $21$.

Source is [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X06002034) that I've linked in the comments earlier.  It considers the optimal strategy for equal-sum dice games with $n$ sides that sum up to some number $\delta$, where all sides are a positive integer.

Your question is answered by the solution to the $(6,21)$ case (stated under "*Example 9*"), which boils down to that the original die is the best option to choose, which was an unexpected result to me at first.

---

### Result explained

The reason behind that is that the regular $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ die has at least an equal chance of winning the game of some amount of "battles" (or rolls) against any of the valid $110$ dice.

All other dice can be matched up with at least one **weak spot** as I call it - a die that has **greater chance of winning** against the given die - making your die have a **greater chance of losing**.

**The original die is the only die that does not have a weak spot.**

Thus, The best die is the original $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ die and both players, playing optimally, clearly have an equal chance of winning.

---

### Some remarks

**If your opponent were to randomly play a die** against your regular die, you would either keep your balanced chances of wining, or have a greater chance to win. Playing the original die, **you can't lose more often than your opponent.** 

*(This is the expected result of course, since surely you can be very unlucky and roll $1$ all the time, but those cases diminish as the amount of battles or games increases)*

**If you were to play any other die against a random die**, you could have an equal chance of winning (overall draw), have a better chance of winning (overall win), or have a greater chance of losing (overall loss).

With the original die, **you can never have an expected overall loss**. All other dice can end up in that situation.

The result of the optimal game boils down to flipping a fair coin to see who'll win, with some chances of the coin being stuck vertically - a draw.

---

User [jvdhooft](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/437988/jvdhooft) had a observation in the comments, where the die $(4,4,4,3,3,3)$ is the same against a regular die, like two regular dice against each other.

Also, it plays better overall against random dice by winning more rolls on average! Does this mean this **is a better die?**

No. Simply because if it were playing against one of its weak spots, such as $(1,1,4,5,5,5)$, it would be expected to lose the match more often. Where the regular die is never expected to lose the match more often.

---

I would say that the regular dice $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ specializes to never have an expected loss more often, while the $(4,4,4,3,3,3)$ specializes at beating lesser dice with a better score on average, but by not being the optimal die, it can end up in a duel where it will lose more often.